# what's the "Contract Creation Code" in Etherscan Verfied Contract?

Tags: etherscan, solc

what's the difference between "Contract Creation Code" in Etherscan Verfied Contract and the bytecode compiled by Solc?

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76334/what-is-the-difference-between-bytecode-init-code-deployed-bytecode-creation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contract Creation Code is the full bytecode from what contract was deployed, including **constructor parameters**.

Comment: Thank you! But if contract doesn`t have a constructor parameter, does it mean the creation code is the same as bytecode compiled by Solc?

Comment: @Tony_Zhou Yes.