# How are there contracts on mainnet that exceed contract size limit?

Tags: contract-deployment

As far as I know, there is a contract size limit on mainnet of 24577 bytes. But I can see contracts with larger deployed bytecode, e.g., https://etherscan.io/address/0x23581767a106ae21c074b2276d25e5c3e136a68b#code

The deployed byte code is 44832 bytes. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are counting hex digits, not bytes. So it’s 44832 ÷ 2 = 22416 bytes, which is within the limit.
2. It’s even lower than 22416, because 22416 is the [contract creation code](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/is-creation-code-and-byte-code-the-same-thing/3117), which includes the constructor code + constructor arguments. Have a look at [this other question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76334/what-is-the-difference-between-bytecode-init-code-deployed-bytedcode-creation). What needs to be within the limit is the deployed bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Everthing @dawrdu said, and this:

The contract size limit didn't exist before hard fork 4, described in EIP-607 which included EIP-170, the contract size limitation. So, contracts deployed prior to that were limited by the block gasLimit and not the explicit cap.

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-607.md

Hope it helps.