# Is it possible to get the "creation bytecode" of an already deployed contract in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, bytecode, compiler

I am looking to get some already deployed code working for myself.

With ethers.js I can get the bytecode in the following way

> ethers.getCode("CONTRACT ADDRESS")

However, this is a deployedBytecode and some code is missing, such as the constructor.
This means that you cannot run it by yourself.

i )Is there any way to get the creation bytecode?

ii)If not, is there any way to run getContractFactory with deployedBytecode?

Comment: You can take a look at this if it helps getting the creation bytecode on-chain: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76334/what-is-the-difference-between-bytecode-init-code-deployed-bytecode-creation

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no straightforward way to get the creation bytecode of a contract through an RPC call or similar. But:

- Verified contracts have the creation bytecode on Etherscan https://etherscan.io/token/0x57f1887a8bf19b14fc0df6fd9b2acc9af147ea85#code
- If the contract deployed by an EOA and not a factory, you can look at the input data of the transaction that created the contract. For example you can see on Etherscan the contract [0xcc7bb2d219a0fc08033e130629c2b854b7ba9195](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xcc7bb2d219a0fc08033e130629c2b854b7ba9195) on Goerli was created with the tx [0xa1762c05ddc58e0164bec6c270cc0f69d8d4d27e78d714b9c40bfa130c88a7a3](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xa1762c05ddc58e0164bec6c270cc0f69d8d4d27e78d714b9c40bfa130c88a7a3). If you look at the "Input Data" field, you'll see the creation code (starting with `0x608060`) and the constructor arguments. Executing this code will result in deploying the contract with the runtime bytecode. There's no RPC call to get the tx that created a contract, you'll need a block explorer or a different index.
- If you have the source code of the contract and the compiler settings, you can recompile the code and access the creation bytecode from the compiler outputs.